# Conditionally call JNI in C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, c-preprocessor

I have C++ code that needs to run on two different environments - one with Java installed, one without. In the Java environment, it will need to make JNI calls.

My current setup is as follows:

Main.cpp:

```
#include "JNIInterface.h"
if(useJNI){
    JNIInterface::DoJNIStuff();
} else {
    DoNormalStuff();
}
```

JNIInterface.h:

```
#include <mutex>
//has no <jni.h> include
...
```

JNIInterface.cpp:

```
#include "JNIInterface.h"
#include <jni.h>
void JNIInterface::DoJNIStuff()
{   std::call_once(jvmFlag, [](){
        //basically all the JVM initialization stuff    
    });
    DoStuff(jvm);
}
```

As expected, on the non-Java environment it results in "The program can't start because JVM.dll is missing from your computer".

It seems like the only way is to avoid including the JNI code at compile time in the preprocessor. Is there a different setup to avoid this issue?

Comment: It is really really necessary that both variants are in one program? (It´s possible of course, but...). Two programs (from the same code with different preprocessor stuff), optionally with some start code to check if Java is there and select the right variant, is easier.

Comment: Yeah, it's the constraint I have to work with. I think I'll just add the jvm.dll even in the case where I don't need to call Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention "DLL" I'll assume Windows. The simple solution is something called delay-loading. This prevents a DLL from being loaded at startup, but only when it's first called. No call, no load, no problem if the DLL is missing. Just a setting in MSVC.

Comment: Even though ultimately I didn't use this, if we had a normal build system this would be the right way to go. Thanks!

Comment: You can also do this from the command line, there's not a lot of magic involved.